# How to filter plist arrays with boolean key value in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to filter for certain strings in my plist array:

```
func SearchC(){
    let pathMC = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myPlistArray", ofType: "plist")
    let dictMC = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathMC!)
    myPlistArray = dictMC!["Questions"]!.mutableCopy() as? Array

    if let questionArray = myPlistArray as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        let answersC = questionArray.filter({
            if let correct = $0["CorrectAnswer"] as? String {
                return correct.uppercaseString == "C"
            }
            return false
        })
        print("\(answersC)")
    }
}
```

I now need to filter for items which have the boolean value of “YES”, or “NO”. I tweaked the code above and came up with the following:

```
func SearchYES(){
    let pathMC = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myPlistArray", ofType: "plist")
    let dictMC = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathMC!)
    myPlistArray = dictMC!["Questions"]!.mutableCopy() as? Array

    if let questionArray = myPlistArray as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        let isFavorite = questionArray.filter({
            if let favorite = $0["isFavorite"] as? String {
                return favorite.uppercaseString == "YES"
            }
            return false
        })
        print("\(isFavorite)")
    }
}
```

BUT it’s not working. Does anyone know how to filter items which have a boolean key value of TRUE/YES?

Comment: Can you print/show the content of `myPlistArray`?

Comment: Cast as Bool and check it. It is not a String

Comment: @leoDabus, how do you cast it as a bool?

Comment: just cast it the same way `as? Bool`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I receive the following error: // value of type 'Bool' has no member 'uppercaseString'.. How should I replace it?

Comment: Do you know what is a Bool type? Just check `if favorite { // do whatever }`